# Sites with up-to-date OpenGL tutorials and examples

Tags: math, opengl

I'm looking for sites with examples and tutorials for OpenGL. The OpenGL SuperBible seemed to be a must-have so I just got it and it seems a bit too complicated for me at the moment due to my lack of math knowledge. Therefore, I have decided to start out with simple 2D-games which shouldn't be that hard. The tutorials and examples need to be up-to-date which seems hard to find. I'd love a very simple 2D game example like Pong or similar that I could build upon.

Also: what math is necessary for 3D-programming? Would it be possible for me to learn most of it by myself or do I have to wait for college/late high school?

Comment: If you just want to create a 2D game, why not use something like Allegro or some other library that is designed for making games? They have all of the stuff you need; raw OpenGL is far more complex than you are ready to handle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in other posts, [NeHe](http://nehe.gamedev.net) is great.  It is getting a bit old though.  [Lighthouse 3D](http://www.lighthouse3d.com) is pretty helpful as well.  For the most up-to-date references, just go straight to [OpenGL](http://www.opengl.org).  It's a great resource.  *[Real-Time Rendering](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1568814240)* is a great book for computer graphics.  The [website](http://www.realtimerendering.com/) has tons of resources as well.

Regarding the math that you should know, linear algebra is a must in computer graphics.  Many computer graphics books will provide an overview of the math that you should be familiar with.  The book I mentioned above (*[Real-Time Rendering](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1568814240)*) provides a great overview.  Another decent book relating to the math required for computer graphics is *[Fundamentals of Computer Graphics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1568814690)*.  There may be better books out there in terms of the math overview that you're looking for, but I've found these two to be helpful.  Be aware, though, that neither of these books will have a lot of examples; they cover some of the more theoretical aspects of computer graphics.

Comment: +1 for some good references but -1 for NeHe : I seem to post this in every "getting started with OpenGL" question but NeHe is horribly outdated, to the point of usually leading a beginner away from the correct way to do things in modern OpenGL.

Answer (score 3):

And of course there's [Nicol Bolas' site](http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/) which is much nicer and more up to date than NeHe and the typical sites that deal with 10-15 year old OpenGL.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend having a look at [Joe's Blog](http://duriansoftware.com/joe/An-intro-to-modern-OpenGL.-Table-of-Contents.html) as well.

For math, have a look at [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1584502770).